# bash script to reboot after usb stick is unplugged

Tags: linux, bash, usb

I have this script in bash tahat should check if the usb device is present in the machine and if is not then reboots it:

```
#!/bin/bash

UNPLUG_MESSAGE="PLEASE UNPLUG THE USB STICK NOW"
export REMOVABLE_DRIVE=""

function dev_detect {
    for _device in /sys/block/*/device; do
        if echo $(readlink -f $_device)|egrep -q "usb"; then
        _disk=`echo $_device | cut -f4 -d/`
        REMOVABLE_DRIVE="$_disk"
    echo "dev_detect_function"
    fi 
done
}

dev_detect

clear

echo $UNPLUG_MESSAGE

sleep 5


function check_usb {
    if [[ $REMOVABLE_DRIVE == *sdb* ]] || [[ $REMOVABLE_DRIVE == *sdc* ]]
    then 
    dev_detect
    echo $REMOVABLE_DRIVE
    echo "PLEASE UNPLUG THE USB STICK";
    sleep 2
    check_usb
    else
    echo "else reboot block"
    sudo reboot
    fi
}


check_usb
```

but when I unplug the usb pendrive it detects the usb :( - where I made mistake?

Comment: You can also `grep "USB disconnect"` in `/var/log/messages` or directly `grep` output of `dmesg`. You will get something like `usb 2-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 101`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write it differently:

```
#! /bin/bash

REMOVABLE_DEVICE=$(find /sys/block/ -type l -printf "%f %l\n" | awk '/usb/{print $1}')

if grep -Eq "(sdb|sdc)" <<< "$REMOVABLE_DEVICE" ;then
    echo "DEVICE IS PRESENT!"
else
    echo "DEVICE NOT PRESENT!" 
fi
```

1. Using `find` is more effective, so you don't need to use `readlink`
   nor `grep`
2. Using `awk`  is more effective, so you don't need to use `grep` nor
   `cut`

I tested this script before posting, I hope it helps :)